# Auto populate vendor and item in Netsuite Purchase Order

Tags: netsuite

I have created a button in the inventory item page that goes that when pressed a work flow action of "Go to record" was created to generate a purchase order.  I would like the purchase order to auto populate the fields vendor and Item from the inventory item page.  This needs a suitescript and I was wondering if anyone has any knowledge on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Create Record action, not the Go to Record.

You can probably get the Vendor and other header fields populated via standard Workflow. The line item (item to order) will have to be done via a Workflow Action Script, as the standard Workflow engine does not support sublists.

But if you're going through all that trouble of a Workflow Action Script just to handle a line item, you may as well just use SuiteScript to do the entire process and have the script called from the button.